# File upload with AJAX and XMLHttpRequest - sending a file to php file

Tags: ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<br><br>
<p>
  <input type="file" id="file_to_upload">
  <button onclick="upload()">Upload</button>
</p>
 
<p id="answer"></p>

<script>

    function upload(){
        var fd = new FormData();
        var files = [];
        files[0] = document.getElementById('file_to_upload').files[0];

        if (files[0].length!=0){
            fd.append('file',files[0]);

            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=this.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","upload.php");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
            xmlhttp.send(fd);
        }  
    
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

From empty file upload.php I receive the message:

> Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0

Could someone tell me what's wrong with my code? I only found exapmles using jquery but I don't want to use it.